# PHP - use include() function within an array

Tags: php, arrays, function, include

How would I use the include() function within an array?

For example, I have an array which lists a bunch of counties, instead of inputting all of the counties into an array, I created a .txt file of comma delimited counties. Logically, I think it's supposed to work as such:

`array (include ("counties.txt"));`

But it produces the list outside of the array's function.

is there a different method of using the include() function within an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want to use [`file('countries.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: oddly enough file() is what did the trick for my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One way is for your `counties.txt` file to have the following format:

```
<?php
return array(
    'country1',
    'country2',
    // etc.
);
```

Then, just include it in your array like:

```
<?php
$arr = include('counties.txt');
```

Another method is to parse `counties.txt` like:

```
<?php
$list = file_get_contents('counties.txt');

// Normalize the linebreaks first
$list = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $list);

// Put each line into its own element within the array
$arr = explode("\n", $list);
```

Either way works and will produce the same result.

Comment: As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php (example #5) on PHP.net, include() does not return the contents of the file; it simply returns `1` unless there is a return statement within the file. In that case, it will return the contents of the `return;` statement. So it wouldn't work with non-.php files anyway. I recommend instead using readfile() or filegetcontents() as is explained in the other answers.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `file_get_contents()`

```
$temp_string = file_get_contents('counties.txt');
$temp_array = array($temp_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try readfile(), separating each county on a new line.  The readfile() function places each line of the file into an indexed array.

```
$array = readfile('counties.txt');
```